# PHP escaping encoded quotes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping

I have following piece of code which posts some data into database:

```
$post = trim( $post );
$post = htmlentities( $post, ENT_QUOTES, null, false );

$statement = "INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (:message)";
$prepared_posts = $pdo->prepare( $statement );
$prepared_posts->execute( array( ':message' => $post ) );
```

I have MySQL version `5.1.47-community` on both localhost and staging / production server, but I'm getting different output on both of them. On localhost I'm running `PHP 5.3.2`, production server has `PHP 5.2.14`.

If I'm trying to post sentence `that's "ok"`, on production it saves `that\&#039;s \&quot;ok\&quot;`, localhost produces correct `that&#039;s &quot;ok&quot;`.

What could be causing this? Could it be some MySQL setting? I also tried using `mysqli` instead of `PDO` and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These additional backslashes could be [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes) so that `that's "ok"` becomes `that\'s \"ok\"`. Try to [disable them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `magic_quotes_gpc` is `on`  in production server and in localhost is `off`.

You can set it using `ini_set` command.

Comment: In fact, manual says you cannot set it using ini_set, but there's a workaround for disabling it at runtime.